# Adding windows.forms control to wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

Any idea of adding windows.forms control to xaml.

I got this code

```
    xmlns:wf="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms;assembly=System.Windows.Forms"
                <WindowsFormsHost Margin="272,10,396,42" Width="240">
                    <wf:TextBox x:Name="txtAutoProductCode" AutoCompleteMode="SuggestAppend" AutoCompleteSource="CustomSource" />
                </WindowsFormsHost>
```

But i got an exception. I am not sure what to do. I am stuck here.

The detailed exception is given below..

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233087
  Message='Initialization of 'Billing.MainWindow' threw an exception.' Line number '6' and line position '9'.
  Source=PresentationFramework
  LineNumber=6
  LinePosition=9
  StackTrace:
       at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)
       at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(XamlReader xamlReader, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlAccessLevel accessLevel, Uri baseUri)
       at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream stream, ParserContext parserContext, Object parent, Boolean closeStream)
       at System.Windows.Application.LoadBamlStreamWithSyncInfo(Stream stream, ParserContext pc)
       at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Uri resourceLocator, Boolean bSkipJournaledProperties)
       at System.Windows.Application.DoStartup()
       at System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__1(Object unused)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
       at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
       at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
       at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
```

Comment: Please post the exception code

Comment: What exception? We're not mind-readers.

Comment: Tell us a question and/or an exception try your idea then if you got problems post it here

Comment: Why are you trying to host a Windows Forms textbox in WPF, are you just trying to get your head around the concept or do you need to do this for a reason?

Comment: It means that the init of the WinForm threw something, making this a follow-up and duplicate of your prev question.

Comment: Actually i am trying to use the autocomplete functionality of the windows textbox, which is not there in wpf.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Object reference not set to an instance of an object.Windows.forms control is causing this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19629432/object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object-windows-forms-control-is-ca)

Comment: @KaMaLMoHaN You could use AutoCompleteBox in the [WPF Toolkit](http://wpf.codeplex.com/), embedding a Windows Form in a WPF Application is just going to get messy!

Comment: the usual reason I host winform controls is because WPF doesnt have a propertygrid...sometimes there is no choice

Comment: I have installed WPF Toolkit, but i thought its more complicated. That's why i tried for this one. Is there any tuts for working with that. Because i am on a deadline of wednesday. I need to complete this project within that.

Comment: @WeylandYutani The extended WPF toolkit also has a [propertygrid control](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=PropertyGrid).

Comment: thanks, but i am not allowed to use 3rd party controls - crazy imo but yeah

Comment: @WeylandYutani can you redirect to the same.

Comment: you are using WindowsFormsHost exactly like i do. The error must be something specific to the textbox. Try removing the autocomplete properties and see if the error goes away.

Comment: @WeylandYutani i changed the properties, now the exception has gone, but i am getting some program error, let me check that. after that how to enable that feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only way I could get it to work was to set the autocomplete properties in code behind. Otherwise I see the same error. But it has to be done after InitializeComponent().

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    txtAutoProductCode.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
    txtAutoProductCode.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Add("item1");
    txtAutoProductCode.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Add("item2");
}

<Grid>
    <WindowsFormsHost Margin="272,10,396,42" Width="240">
        <wf:TextBox x:Name="txtAutoProductCode" AutoCompleteMode="SuggestAppend"/>
    </WindowsFormsHost>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Yes you are right. But i didn't add the auto complete properties, it's showing while i run the program. I assume its another easy way to add autofill property. Right?

Answer (score 0):

As said by @WeylandYutani, i removed the autocomplete properties from the xaml code. It worked fine.

First add reference to WindowsFormsIntegration and System.Windows.Forms

Then add using System.Windows.Forms as the namespace

XAML

```
    xmlns:wf="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms;assembly=System.Windows.Forms"
                <WindowsFormsHost Margin="272,10,396,42" Width="240">
                    <wf:TextBox x:Name="txtAutoProductCode" />
                </WindowsFormsHost>
```

AutoComplete Function

```
    void Auto_Complete()
    {
        txtAutoProductCode.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
        txtAutoProductCode.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
        AutoCompleteStringCollection coll = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();

        SqlCeCommand com = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT ProductCode FROM Products_Master", con);
        SqlCeDataReader dr;
        con.Open();
        try
        {
            dr = com.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                string aProduct = dr.GetString(0);
                coll.Add(aProduct);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, System.Windows.Forms.Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        txtAutoProductCode.AutoCompleteCustomSource = coll;
        con.Close();
    }
```

Add Auto_Complete(); after InitializeComponent();

RUN IT.