# Usage of StreamWriter

Tags: c#, streamwriter

I'm using the following code to open a file and then trying to write something to it:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    StreamWriter file = null;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        using (file = new StreamWriter("../data/floorPlane.txt", true))
        {
            file.WriteLine("x \t y \t z \t w \n");
        }
    }
}
```

But it always gives the following error:

> A first chance exception of type
>   'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in
>   PresentationFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: 'The invocation of the constructor on type
>   'SkeletalViewer.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding
>   constraints threw an exception.

I'm totally new to c#. Maybe the question is kindof stupid.

Thanks,

Comment: Your exception has nothing to do with the code you are showing

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9045378/xaml-parse-exception-xmlnsx-http-schemas-microsoft-com-winfx-2006-xaml

Comment: Obviously there's another problem in there. Read the exception carefully. There's a problem with some binding.

Comment: Are you sure you have given the **correct** *relative path* of txt file ?

Comment: I believe the actual reason of the exception is your path.

Comment: Exceptions which occur in the ctor of a WPF control will have this exception. You must look in the inner exception to see the actual problem.

Comment: the relative path has problem!!! Thanks!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

First, check the inner exception to see what you are actually messing up. Then, if the answer is still not apparent, compare your code to the sample found at this MSDN article:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.io.streamwriter

Answer (score 0):

this exception is caught many times. You can press **ctrl+alt+E** to **check all exception** and than you can find real exception.